# Show results in Datagridview based on DateTimePicker Value

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, calculated-columns

I'm trying to make this datagridview show only the date records that was chosen by the user through datetimepicker

here is my original code without the datetimepicker

```
    private void frmSaleReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User Id=;Password=;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb");
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales ORDER BY DayDate;", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView2.Columns["InvoiceNo"].HeaderText = "رقم الفاتورة";
    dataGridView2.Columns["InvoiceNo"].Width = 150;
    dataGridView2.Columns["DayDate"].HeaderText = " التاريخ";
    dataGridView2.Columns["DayDate"].Width = 350;
    dataGridView2.Columns["Gross"].HeaderText = "الإجمالي";
    dataGridView2.Columns["Gross"].Width = 150;
    dataGridView2.Columns["Net"].HeaderText = " الصافي";
    dataGridView2.Columns["Net"].Width = 150;
    dataGridView2.Columns["Staff"].HeaderText = " الموظف";
    dataGridView2.Columns["Staff"].Width = 150;
    conn.Close();
    GrandTotal();
    Qty();
}
private void Qty()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    }
    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
private void GrandTotal()
{
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    }
    textBox3.Text = sum2.ToString();
}
```

Now if I try to add the where statement, it starts giving me error in debugging mode about data type mismatch, how can i get this to work?

here is the link I use for datetimepicker

```
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where DayDate = '"dateFrom.Value"'ORDER BY DayDate;", conn);
```

Comment: You need to use a "+" sign for concat the sql string with the datetime value. Or use string interpolation.

Comment: Looking at what you're doing, you might want to think about setting a rowfilter on the default view of your data. This will keep you from hitting the database every time someone changes a date. EDIT: Also, once you fix the issue Luis expressed, dates in Access are wrapped in # not '

Comment: Hello @Luis & Charles. I tried that, not getting errors but also not getting any value back

Answer (score 0):

You need proper formatting when concatenating a date value expression:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where DayDate = #" + dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#;", conn);
```

Edit: To remove a time part:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where Fix(DayDate) = #" + dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#;", conn);
```

or:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where DayDate >= #" + dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# And DayDate < #" + dateFrom.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#;", conn);
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I've tried that but it gave me this error Syntax error in date in query expression 'DayDate = #05/DD/YYYY'.

Comment: ok, it was my mistake, I put the MM in small case, but still now doesn't give an error but not returning any record

Comment: Then your `DayDate` probably contains a time part.